# Change content property of pseudo element within CSS animation

Tags: css

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to change the content of a pseudo element (`:before` or `:after`) within a CSS animation.

It doesn't seem to be working in my fiddle, but maybe there's another way: http://jsfiddle.net/xfrfnav1/

Comment: I don't think that 'property' is animatable. Anyway, it shouln't be used for actual 'content' although I do think this is a edge case.

Comment: `content` isn't an animatable property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content. If you think about it, how would the browser know how to tween between `content: 'foo';` and `content: 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting suggestion, but apparently the browser (Chrome in my case) ignores the content. Makes a little sense. After all, it is for an animation, and the property is 'morphed' from one value to another gradually, which is not possible with content. Still, it would be nice of it worked.

A possible solution: put all the dots in there already and change the width. If you like, you can put the text 'loading' in `:before` (or in the `div` itself) and the dots in `:after`, so you can easily animate it from `0` to any desired width:

```
div:before { 
    content:"Loading"; 
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden; /* Weird baseline behavior without this */
} 
div:after { 
    content:"......................."; 
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide the dots */
    -webkit-animation: loading 4s linear 0 infinite;
} 

@-webkit-keyframes loading {
    0% { width: 0;} /* Only from and to are needed */
    100% { width: 3em;}
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhf6a6Lo/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xfrfnav1/1/)
I have added a fixed width on parent div, and Loading directly in content, your problem was `content:"";` with no content is hard to show text

My css :

```
div { width: 61px; }

div:after {
    content:"Loading...";
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden; /* animation gonna reduce content width so points gonna hide */
    -webkit-animation:loading 1s linear 0 infinite;
} 

@-webkit-keyframes loading { /* be careful you must add -moz and other browser prefixed versions */
    0% { width:80% }
    25% { width:85% }
    50% { width:90% }
    100% { width:100% }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine (at least in Chrome) if you change to: `-webkit-animation:loading 1s infinite linear;`